# Unable to attain an output after running main.dart I/flutter (15748): Observatory listening on ************************************

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, port, android-11

[image: output]

I usually run my apps on my physical device. But 2 days ago I updated it to Android 11(Vivo Z1 Pro)and after the update, I couldn't do it. It is just gets stuck on

`I/flutter (15748): Observatory listening on ************************************`

The app gets updated but I can't get any live update...like hot reload etc

Comment: same exact device and problem here

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: which mobile device u r using?

Comment: Android 11(Vivo Z1 Pro)

Comment: @InderPalSingh Vivo Z1 Pro with recent update to Android 11

Comment: Getting the same issue, but the app runs if you close it on your phone (remove from RAM) and then start again on your phone itself.

Comment: yeah...but you cant hot-reload :(

Comment: I have the same issue in the same device

Comment: If anyone finds a solution make sure you share it here too

Comment: having same issue in vivo v20 as well after updating to phone version PD2039F_EX_A_1.15.1

Comment: Same issue with the same device after android 11 update.

Comment: does anyone getting api url as ********* after update vivo? in android native project

Comment: I got as Observatory listening on *********

Answer (score 0):

This is a device specific issue and the bug is tracked in this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82520). No other known workarounds for this behavior aside from [upgrading the affected device to Android 12](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82520#issuecomment-1098735580).